# Como capturar o último elemento de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Em PHP, para pegar o último elemento de um *array* posso fazer assim:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);

echo end($array); // 3;
```

E em Python? Como eu poderia fazer isso com essa lista:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Agarra pelo rabo :)

Comment: Em python talvez não seja o caso, mas dependendo da espécie tem que tirar o guizo antes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basta pegar o índice negativo. Vale para qualquer elemento, não só o último. A ideia é que na verdade ele está pegando o `length` mais aquele valor, como é negativo, ele vai pegando ao contrário. Obviamente que o número não pode ser maior que o `length`. Nesse exemplo só poderia usar -3, que é o tamanho da lista, e o -3 pegaria o primeiro elemento. Obviamente pode usar uma variável e ser criativo.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
print(arr[-1])
print(arr[-2])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HvhECq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eprbnvtg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/LastElement.py).

Esta é uma solução adotada por algumas linguagens, assim não precisa de uma função específica ou algum malabarismo matemático, fica bem curto e expressivo.

Answer (score 9):

Coloca o -1 entre colchetes:

```
arr[-1]
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/d8j1DY).