# Como faço para atribuir a uma variável o ultimo valor de um vetor?

Tags: python

Preciso colocar em uma variável o último valor de um vetor, problema é que esse vetor pode variar de tamanho. Existe alguma função direta que traz o ultimo valor do vetor?

Tentei utilizar uma variável para verificar o tamanho do vetor, porém não funcionou, abaixo um pouco do código

```
ultimo = len(tensao)
mod_elasticidade = tensao[ultimo]
```

Comment: Quando as respostas fornecidas responderem a sua questão a contento, considere marca-las como aceitas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como capturar o último elemento de uma lista em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176232/como-capturar-o-%c3%baltimo-elemento-de-uma-lista-em-python)

Answer (score 3):

Existe a possibilidade de utilizar as posições de forma invertida, array[-1], array[-2], e assim por diante. Exemplo:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(array[-1])
#O retorno será '5'
print(array[-2])
#O retorno será '4'
```

Então:

```
mod_elasticidade = tensao[-1]
```

Se queres fazer utilizando a função `len()` também podes, você estava recebendo erro, pois a função `len()` retorna o números de elementos contando a partir do 1:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(len(array))
#O retorno será '5'
```

Já as posições, são contadas a partir do 0, e nesse exemplo vão de 0 a 4:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
#A posição 0 é o 1, a 1 é o 2, e assim em diante
print(array[0])
#O retorno será '1'
print(array[4])
#O retorno será '5'
```

Então:

```
ultimo = len(tensao)-1 # -1, para reduzir essa diferença

mod_elasticidade = tensao[ultimo]
```

Answer (score 0):

A função `len()` retorna a quantidade de elementos contidos em uma lista.

Em `Python`, o primeiro elemento de uma lista possui índice `0`, enquanto o último elemento possui índice `len() - 1`.

```
idx_ultimo = len(tensao) - 1
mod_elasticidade = tensao[ idx_ultimo ]
```

Computacionalmemnte falando, recuperar o ultimo elemento de uma lista trata-se de uma operação muito comum de ser executada, e em `Python`, tudo pode ficar muito mais simples por meio da `slice notation`:

```
mod_elasticidade = tensao[-1]  # Retorna o ultimo elemento da lista.
```

É bom lembrar que a tentativa de se acessar o ultimo elemento de uma lista vazia causa uma exceção do tipo `IndexError`. Uma possivel solução para se tratar este caso sem que ocorra uma exceção seria algo como:

```
mod_elasticidade = tensao[-1] if tensao else None
```